# what is LC_TERMINAL_VERSION in my env?

Tags: environment-variables

when typing `env` in my terminal one of the results is `LC_TERMINAL_VERSION`.

I've been wondering what it is, or if there's a way to get documentation on the different env vars that exist in my terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have two variables:

```
LC_TERMINAL=<terminal name>     (i.e. "bash")
LC_TERMINAL_VERSION=<version>   (the version of that LC_TERMINAL)
```

These variables can be used by tools that open a shell such as `ssh`. There are all sorts of ways to find out what shell to use when running ssh (and in the old days, telnet). Such variables make it easier.

The `LC` at the start mean *locale*. These parameters are used to define your locale: how to write phone numbers, a price, the date, the name of the month, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from Alexis is the right answer for locale variables in general, and is good enough. I’m here to provide supplemental information for this specific variable, in case anyone is interested.

This variable was made popular by [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/), which is the only terminal (AFAIK) that exports them *by default*. iTerm2 actually exports two pairs of variables:

1. `$TERM_PROGRAM` and `$TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION`: this is to be compatible with [Apple Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_macOS_built-in_apps#Terminal). Apple Terminal sets `$TERM_PROGRAM` to `Apple_Terminal`.
2. `$LC_TERMINAL` and `$LC_TERMINAL_VERSION`: this is meant to be passed through SSH.

`$LC_TERMINAL` and `$LC_TERMINAL_VERSION` are passed by SSH because many SSH servers have this in their SSH daemon configuration:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

which matches any variable starting with `LC` and an underscore. About how that works, see [this answer in Unix SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299037/pass-variable-in-ssh#299042).